# Having Problems with tests in CDK-Workshop (typescript): Inline source not allowed for nodejs14.x

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am currently working through the cdk-workshop provided by amazon: https://cdkworkshop.com. I followed all the steps (at least I hope) and have created a test program and deployed it. I the current step I am tasked to create assertion tests for my constructs: https://cdkworkshop.com/20-typescript/70-advanced-topics/100-construct-testing/1000-assertion-test.html

However already in the first test (DynamoDB Table Created), where the workshop asks me to run

```
$ npm run build && npx jest
```

I am having trouble:

[image]

Googling for the error "Inline source not allowed for nodejs14.x" did not help me.

For extra information I will add the exact code as well as my package.json:

[image]
[image]

Also, I just ran cdk deploy and the base program of the workshop works and can be called by me.
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the CDK, they should be able to tell when we are just running tests.

I used `runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,`. In reality, you just want to test that `HitCounter` creates a DynamoDB table so I believe it's ok for you to use something like this:

```js
test('Dynamo DB table created', () => {
    const stack = new cdk.Stack();

    new HitCounter(stack, 'MyTestConstruct', {
        downstream: new lambda.Function(stack, 'TestFunction', {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
            code: lambda.Code.fromInline('test'),
            handler: 'index.handler'
        }),
    });

    expectCDK(stack).to(haveResource('AWS::DynamoDB::Table'))
})
```